# Why are the poles of the stator and rotor taken differently in the picture below?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, electric-machine, magnetic-flux

The rotor and stator in the picture below have the same orientation of flux lines yet the are taken as opposite that is flux lines leaving the stator is taken as a South Pole while flux lines leaving the rotor is taken as a North Pole. Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Magnetic lines of flux follow a convention and that convention is that lines of flux (leaving the "core") flow from a north pole to a south pole (through the air): -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Flux lines leaving both are labeled North.  The stator is the ring structure, hollow in the middle to accept the rotor.